# How to show post thumbnail in wordpress front page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following code written in function.php in my wordpress.

```
function wptuts_recentpost2($atts, $content=null){
$getpost = get_posts( array('number' => 1, 'offset' => 1) );
$getpost = $getpost[0];
$return = $getpost->post_thumbnail . "<br />" . $getpost->post_title . "<br />" . $getpost->post_excerpt . "…";
$return .= "<br /><a href='" . get_permalink($getpost->ID) . "'><em>read more →</em></a>";
return $return;
}
add_shortcode('newestpost2', 'wptuts_recentpost2');
```

What should I write here to display thumbnails?

I tried adding

```
$getpost = $get_post->post_thumbnail
```

But it didn't work... :(

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "What should I add here to display thumbnails?"

Comment: thanks @Chris I just added extra detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `get_the_post_thumbnail($getpost->ID)`.

Please refter to the codex
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

This will return the thumbnail image tag.